# Generate all permutations of a string containing repeated characters

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

I was writing a program to print all the permutations of a string. I came up with the following:

```
void permute(string s,string r){
    if(s.length()==0){
        cout<<r<<endl;
        return;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        permute(s.substr(0,i)+s.substr(i+1,s.length()-i-1),r+s[i]);
    }
}
```

However, this prints duplicates in case the string has repeated characters. Can anyone please help me figure out a way to avoid duplicates (not using a set, of course)?

Comment: FWIW, there's an ancient and efficient algorithm for this. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Generation_in_lexicographic_order for Narayana Pandita's algorithm from 14th century India.

Answer (score 0):

We build the permutation from consecutive blocks of equal values.

The trick  here is  to group  the output in  blocks of  repeated equal
values and ensure  that when a block is being  followed by another the
second block  is certain  to repeat a  different value than  the first
one. This  removes the ambiguity  that would arise if  the permutation
were being built one item at a time.

This is the Perl code.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub permute {
    my ($avail, $prev, $sofar, $pos, $n) = @_;

    if($pos == $n){
        print(join('-', @$sofar) . "\n");
        return;
    }

    my @possibles = keys %$avail;
    foreach my $item (@possibles){
        if(!($item eq $prev)){
            for(my $len = 1; $len <= $avail->{$item}; $len++){
                $avail->{$item} -= $len;
                delete $avail->{$item} if $avail->{$item} == 0;
                push @$sofar, ($item) x $len;

                permute($avail, $item, $sofar, $pos+$len, $n);

                splice @$sofar, $pos, $len;
                $avail->{$item} += $len;
            }
        }
    }
}

 MAIN: {
     my $str = shift || 'ABCD';
     my @chars = split //, $str;

     my %multiset;
     map { $multiset{$_}++ } @chars;

     permute(\%multiset, 'VOID', [], 
            0, scalar(@chars));
}
```

Here are some sample runs.

```
$ time ./permute.pl 1234
4-1-3-2
4-1-2-3
4-3-1-2
4-3-2-1
4-2-1-3
4-2-3-1
1-4-3-2
1-4-2-3
1-3-4-2
1-3-2-4
1-2-4-3
1-2-3-4
3-1-4-2
3-1-2-4
3-4-1-2
3-4-2-1
3-2-4-1
3-2-1-4
2-1-4-3
2-1-3-4
2-4-1-3
2-4-3-1
2-3-4-1
2-3-1-4

real    0m0.071s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.031s

$ time ./permute.pl abab
a-b-a-b
a-b-b-a
a-a-b-b
b-a-b-a
b-a-a-b
b-b-a-a

real    0m0.061s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.046s

$ time ./permute.pl xabab
a-b-a-b-x
a-b-a-x-b
a-b-x-a-b
a-b-x-b-a
a-b-b-a-x
a-b-b-x-a
a-x-a-b-b
a-x-b-a-b
a-x-b-b-a
a-a-b-x-b
a-a-b-b-x
a-a-x-b-b
b-a-b-a-x
b-a-b-x-a
b-a-x-a-b
b-a-x-b-a
b-a-a-b-x
b-a-a-x-b
b-x-a-b-a
b-x-a-a-b
b-x-b-a-a
b-b-a-x-a
b-b-a-a-x
b-b-x-a-a
x-a-b-a-b
x-a-b-b-a
x-a-a-b-b
x-b-a-b-a
x-b-a-a-b
x-b-b-a-a

real    0m0.063s
user    0m0.030s
sys     0m0.030s

$ time ./permute.pl xyxyxy
y-x-y-x-y-x
y-x-y-x-x-y
y-x-y-y-x-x
y-x-x-y-x-y
y-x-x-y-y-x
y-x-x-x-y-y
y-y-x-y-x-x
y-y-x-x-y-x
y-y-x-x-x-y
y-y-y-x-x-x
x-y-x-y-x-y
x-y-x-y-y-x
x-y-x-x-y-y
x-y-y-x-y-x
x-y-y-x-x-y
x-y-y-y-x-x
x-x-y-x-y-y
x-x-y-y-x-y
x-x-y-y-y-x
x-x-x-y-y-y

real    0m0.054s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.061s
```

**Addendum.** I just realized that the OP probably does not admit this solution because it uses a multiset stored in a hash table. However the hash table can be removed and replaced with a sorted list being spliced to extract the blocks. That would seem to mean that the basic idea of the algorithm is sound.

**Addendum II.** Here  is an implementation that only  uses arrays and
no hash tables, which is not as  fast as the first one. This should be
sufficient as a building block  for a C implementation, one just needs
to optimize that array splicing that takes place.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub permute {
    my ($avail, $prev, $sofar, $pos, $n) = @_;

    if($pos == $n){
        print(join('-', @$sofar) . "\n");
        return;
    }

    my $avails = scalar(@$avail); my $ind = 0;
    while($ind < $avails){
        my $item = $avail->[$ind];

        my $run = 1;
        while($ind+$run < $avails &&
              $avail->[$ind+$run] eq $item){
            $run++;
        }


        if(!($item eq $prev)){
            for(my $len = 1; $len <= $run; $len++){
                push @$sofar, ($item) x $len;
                splice @$avail, $ind, $len;

                permute($avail, $item, $sofar, $pos+$len, $n);

                splice @$avail, $ind, 0, ($item) x $len;
                splice @$sofar, $pos, $len;
            }
        }

        $ind += $run;
    }
}

 MAIN: {
     my $str = shift || 'ABCD';
     my @chars = split //, $str;

     my @sorted = sort @chars;

     permute(\@sorted, 'VOID', [], 
            0, scalar(@chars));
}
```